# Can anyone help me figure out why i am receiving this error?

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbiIs.png)

I am trying to spell check txt files in python using a class and do not know why this error is showing up

Answer (score 0):

NameError implies that you did not define the variable before using it. You need to assign numWord something before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Because line 18 to 21 are not indented and so, out of the function. numWord is defined only inside of the function, considering it is an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You created a function named "get_file" but didn't call it. 
You have to just add "return count, numWord" in the end of the function then call it as "count, numWord = get_file()". Hope this will work :-).